# ViewModifier react to changes - generic toast alert

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using a toast library to show error or success alerts.

For the generic ones, i don't want to write all the code in lots of places so i tried to create a generic view modifier

```
struct ErrorToast: ViewModifier {
    
    let actionCompletedViewModel: ActionCompletedViewModel
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toast(isPresenting: .constant(actionCompletedViewModel.error != nil), duration: 2, tapToDismiss: true,
                   alert: {
                let errorMessage = actionCompletedViewModel.error?.errorDescription
                let errorTitle = actionCompletedViewModel.error?.title
                
                return AlertToast(displayMode: .alert, type: .error(.red), title: errorTitle, subTitle: errorMessage)
            }, onTap: {
                actionCompletedViewModel.handleErrorAndClear()
            })
    }
}
```

The `ActionCompletedViewModel` is a class that's being inherited by all view models

```
class ActionCompletedViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var error: CustomError?
    @Published var success: CustomSuccess?

    func assignError(error: CustomError) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
            self?.error = error
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

In my view structs I simply attach the modifier

```
struct AView: View {

@ObservedObject var aViewModel = AVIEWModel.shared

var body: some View {
    VSTack {
        Button {
          aViewModel.doAction()
        }
    }
     .errorToast(aViewModel: aViewModel)
   }
}

class AViewModel: ActionCompletedViewModel, ObservableObject {

  func doAction() {
    someOtherAction() { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success(let success): self.assignSuccess(sucess: success)
                case .failure(let error): self.assignError(error: error)
                }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the toast isn't shown, it doesn't react to the error field being assigned an error

Scenario:
If i'm on screen A and then go to Screen B, execute an action, error is thrown - the error alert isn't shown - and i go back to A and then back to B, the error alert is shown - that tells me the error variable is assigned correctly and that the rendering is done statically

[Github gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/alexantonica/23fcdee8381dca35ec6ae4045ebb41ef)

Edit:

- tried adding `@ObservedObject` to `actionCompletedViewModel` in ErrorToast. Not working

Edit2:

- created a project that exemplifies my problem [repo](https://github.com/alexantonica/swift-binding-example)

Comment: You need to use the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper — otherwise your views don’t know to react to updates.

Comment: Can. you be a little more specific?

Comment: `let aViewModel = AVIEWModel.shared` should be `@ObservedObject var aViewModel =  AVIEWModel.shared`

Comment: I already do that. doesn't work. I've modified the question. Sorry about that, i've forgot to mention it.

Comment: You still don't have it set in your modifier

Comment: Tried it now. Doesn't work

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: It's possible that the `ViewModifier` doesn't listen to the `ObservedObject` wrapper and you would need to pass in the changes explicitly from a `View` that does use that wrapper. But, to test, it'd be useful to have the MRE

Comment: Added the repo to the question @jnpdx. 
Edit: actually it works with the ObservedObject on the View modifier. Can you post your comment as answer so i can accept it pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftUI, property wrappers (like `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject`) are often used to annotate reference types (like an `ObservableObject`) and tell the `View` that it should watch that object for updates.

Without these wrappers, the `View` (or `ViewModifier` in this case) has no notification that it should recalculate/re-render.

In your example, you need to add `@ObservedObject` before both of your `var actionCompletedViewModel: ActionCompletedViewModel` declarations.